# when updating sphinx searchd.pid file is missing, how to solve this?

Tags: indexing, sphinx

I am new to sphinx. While rebooting the server, Sphinx running there stopped and I can't update it:

```
>>root@server [~]# /usr/local/bin/indexer --config /usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf --rotate --all
  >> Sphinx 2.1.9-release (rel21-r4761)
  Copyright (c) 2001-2014, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2014, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

>>using config file '/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'mp3search'...
WARNING: Attribute count is 0: switching to none docinfo
collected 3382548 docs, 197.0 MB
WARNING: sort_hits: merge_block_size=132 kb too low, increasing mem_limit may improve performance
sorted 694.6 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 3382548 docs, 196994320 bytes
total 485.060 sec, 406123 bytes/sec, 6973.46 docs/sec
total 23971 reads, 25.528 sec, 131.3 kb/call avg, 1.0 msec/call avg
total 6982 writes, 36.447 sec, 953.1 kb/call avg, 5.2 msec/call avg
WARNING: failed to open pid_file '/home/local/public_html/sphinx/logs/searchd.pid'.
WARNING: indices NOT rotated.
```

`searchd.pid` file is missing, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx service doesn't start at boot on your system. Check how a service must be installed, depending of your distribution. In general you should have a `searchd` ( or `sphinxsearch` file in /etc/init.d and you need to add the service to the runlevels ( with update-rc.d, chckconfig etc. depending on distribution). You may have the searchd starting script, but for some reason it can't start searchd (try a manual service start, like `service searchd start` , see if works or if gives any error).
Indexer gives you the warning about the pid file because this file is created by searchd ( manually starting searchd you do the index rotation).

Answer (score 0):

In my case using `Fedora 21`, the `PIDFile` setting in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/searchd.service` was different to what was set in `/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf` so searchd didn't come up at boot time. Thanks for the tip above.